# Does Ctrl+F5 differ with F5 for current browsers any more?

Tags: browser, keyboard-shortcuts

From my own experience there's no difference, but still some folks stick to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>F5</kbd>, why?

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference, at least in IE. <kbd>F5</kbd> reissues the request, but does not invalidate the cache. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> invalidates the cache and then reisssues the request.

I suspect other browsers also do the same.

Comment: Some browsers don't though. Opera for instance will reload all tabs on Ctrl+F5 (at least, it did the last time I used it)

Comment: Google Chrome and Firefox do the same as IE.

Comment: Overloading de facto standard actions with different meaning is one of the reasons Opera was never successful. Given that at some point IE had 95+% of the browser market, it is reasonable to expect that the majority of the users are already trained to expect certain behavior on Ctrl-F5, and changing it makes the user ever so slightly aware that something's not exactly right when using Opera.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see any different just because you don't use a caching proxy. Under IE / Google Chrome, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>  would not send a `If-Modified-Since` header.

Just <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```
GET http://www.w3.org/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: zh-HK,zh-tw;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.w3.org
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

server reply `200 Success`

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```
GET http://www.w3.org/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: zh-HK,zh-tw;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 04 Nov 2010 13:10:24 GMT; length=27844
Host: www.w3.org
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

server reply `304 Not Modified`.

Note, IE is issuing `Pragma: no-cache` in most case, only the `If-Modified-Since` header is different

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you press <kbd>F5</kbd> the response of the server would be 200 OR 304 (if your browser contains the cached copy of the file). When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> you will get only 200s, a 304 won't be sent at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> was a forced refresh x-browser, but nowadays browsers tend to cache more and more just to justify for their claims of being the fastest in the market. This can be a problem in webdevelopment and for FF I was using webdevelopement plugin which allows you to disable all forms of caching. I can't recommend you on how to disable all caching in other browsers.